# AWS S3 iOS SDK 2 Retry rules on image upload

Tags: ios, image-processing, amazon-s3, afnetworking-2, connectivity

I'm trying to add a retry to my Amazon S3 image upload. I set the following on my configuration manager:

configuration.maxRetryCount = 3; See code snippet below. Its not doing anything. Do I need to set the retryHandler and if so how do I do this?

```
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:kAmazonAccessKeyId secretKey:kAmazonSecretKey];
    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                          credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
    configuration.maxRetryCount = 3;


    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

    self.transferManager = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
```

Alternatively I'd like to just suspend the queue and then when connectivity is successful un suspend the queue but this doesn't work either. I try the following:

```
     [[self.transferManager putObject:requestObject] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor executorWithOperationQueue:uploadQueue] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
```

but although the queue does suspend correctly (using AFNetworkReachabilityManager successfully to do this). when the queue starts back up it just fails on upload right away with a connectivity time out.

Something I'm doing wrong. I can't find much of any documentation on the AWS retry stuff for V.2

Thanks,
Jennie